# Watchdog message about CPU soft lockup in Fedora

Tags: fedora, kde, cpu, swap, lock

I am running Fedora 34 KDE on my ASUS ZenBook Flip 14 with an Intel 11th Gen i7. It seems like every few minutes, I get this error message:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s! [swapper/7:0]
```

It shows up as a Plasma notification, and it prints the message in every open Konsole window, and it shows up in dmesg. Everything usually freezes for several seconds while this happens.

Setting `tsc=unstable` in the GRUB kernel options seems to fix the problem, but that causes the touchpad to freeze whenever I reopen the lid. The touch screen still works, but not the touchpad.

How can I fix the problem with the soft lockup? Failing that, how can I fix it so that the touchpad doesn't freeze after awaking from suspend?

Comment: Disable your watchdog, if not needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the threshold for the watchdog like so:

```
echo 20 > /proc/sys/kernel/watchdog_thresh
```